# How to pass object instance to <a href> tag within a Django modal dialog?

Tags: django, django-templates, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

In my Django application, I have a delete button to delete a particular file instance.

```
 {% for file in file_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ file.filename }}</td>
        <td>
            <!-- passing the file.pk argument to JS function -->
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#fileConfirmDeleteModal" data-id="{% url 'delete_file' file.pk %}">
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr> 
 {% endfor %}
```

In my JavaScript function call I am displaying the modal confirmation box to delete the file:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
     var file_pk = $(this).data('id'); //the 'file.pk' instance is retrieved

     //how to pass 'file_pk' argument to the <a href> tag in the modal
     $(".modal-footer #delete_file_href").val( file_pk );

     $('#fileConfirmDeleteModal').modal('show');
    });
  </script>
```

Below is the Modal dialog which contains a 'Yes' and 'No' button; on clicking 'Yes', a specific URL pattern needs to be called i.e. 'delete_file' file.pk

```
     <!--Modal: fileConfirmDeleteModal-->
       <div class="modal fade" id="fileConfirmDeleteModal" tabindex="-1"   role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
           <!--Content-->
             <div class="modal-content text-center">
             <!--Header-->
                <p class="heading">Are you sure?</p>
             <!--Body-->
                <div class="modal-footer flex-center">
                 <!--Here I need to append the file.pk value to the 'delete_file url name'-->
                  <a href="{% url 'delete_file' file.pk=file_pk %}" id="delete_file_href">
                    <button>Yes</button>
                  </a>
                   <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
               </div>
             </div>
          <!--/.Content-->
          </div>
      </div>
```

On attempting the above code, I encounter the following error:

```
 Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /mysite/file_log/
 Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: '=file_pk' from 'file.pk=file_pk'
```

The urlpattern being:

```
  path('delete_file/<int:pk>', views.FileDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_file'),
```

I am unable to understand how to append that variable value 'file_pk' to inside the url name {% %} of href tag.

Comment: What is this piece of code supposed to mean? Show your delete_file pattern. ps don't post text as images. Error message here is text.

Comment: why do you need js, you can simply use modal classes from bootstrap.

Comment: Does your `FileDeleteView` delete something on a GET request? You should consider putting your delete button inside a form with method=post and make it a submit button, so an actual POST request triggers the deletion, as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Template error, the argument name (`file_pk`) should be written first, then the value (`file.pk`):

```html
{% url 'delete_file' file_pk=file.pk %}
```

For the modale problem, in your first template, you can pass the delete URL as a `data-delete-url` parameter:

```html
{% for file in file_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ file.filename }}</td>
        <td>
            <!-- passing the file.pk argument to JS function -->
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#fileConfirmDeleteModal"
               data-id="{{ file.pk }}" data-delete-url="{% url 'delete_file' file_pk=file.pk %}"> 
               <button>Delete</button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr> 
 {% endfor %}
```

Then you update the modale URL with this value:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
     var delete_url = $(this).data('delete-url'); 
     $(".modal-footer #delete_file_href").prop( delete_url );

     $('#fileConfirmDeleteModal').modal('show');
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: the data_delete_url is a good idea. I implemented your code, and the template is also getting rendered successfully, and the modal dialog is also getting displayed. However, on clicking 'Yes', the file does not get deleted

Comment: However, I have kept the data_delete_url  value = 'file.pk'; the 'file_pk=file.pk' does not render the template, instead throws an error

Comment: and in the href tag, I have removed the current value from it, now it is:  <a href="" id="delete_file_href" name="delete_file_href"><button class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button></a>, Yet somehow the url is not working, maybe the value is not getting assigned properly to the href tag

Comment: you can't set the `href` attribute using `val()`, use `.prop('href', delete_url)` instead.

Comment: @dirkgroten I tried your solution, still doesn't work